# Inline-block, not lining up

Tags: html, css, inline, display

I'm having trouble getting my divs to line up horizontally.

Here's my html doc: https://gist.github.com/Keenangp/9def2bd08eb6244bcf2d
I don't have enough rep to post the style sheet too, but it goes:

```
.container {
     width: 80%;
     margin: auto;
   }
.column {
     display:inline-block
   }
.image {
     display:inline-block
   }
```

Here's the page: keenansportfolio.bitballoon.com/about

**Some things I've tried while going through previous solutions here:**

When I check the divs in Chrome dev tools, I see that the inline block property has been applied, and there are no errors in the console. I've tried removing the container rule, removing the container div, so the other divs aren't nested. I've tried using a smaller image, combining the property with float: left, and applying inline-block with the class>direct descendant as a selector. I've also tried each div by itself, and applying the vertical-align: top property in case the baseline was interfering with it, and opening it in different browsers.

This is for an exercise, and I wasn't told to edit any other values or add any other properties. I'm kinda stumped.

Answer (score 0):

You want to align three columns in a row if I get it right.

You have to set width of each columns and sum of those are not supposed to exceed container's width. Set width for all three columns (ex:32%) and if you want to align them even if sum of their widths exceed the container's, add this property to container; white-space:nowrap.

Comment: Hey Inpyo, editing the width worked! That really should have been included in the exercise. Question: When I include the white-space:nowrap property, my text shambles off the screen as if it was applying to text, not whitespace.

Comment: @Keenanp Did you apply it to container? If you did, the issue is probably caused by inheritance. You may want to delete the property and set the children's width right.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set 'div width' for "image","column" classes. For example,

```
.image, .column 
  {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 30%;
  }
```

Comment: Excellent, this worked. For some reason I couldn't stack both the image and column selectors, but when I divided them into separate rules, it worked! Thank you v. much. :) (edit: When you answered, I was wondering if that was the issue and started looking at ways to auto-fit the text boxes. The percentage solution is spot on)